# how to have a new value for each new user for time function in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I just wanted that `${__time(yyyyMMddHHmmss)}` should have its new value for each new user in Http samplers

What I have tried is:
* Used loop controller 
* Used counter config element 
etc. but still unable to produce a new values for this time function

Regards,
AA

Comment: Suppose the followings: For **USER-1** the value of ${__time(yyyyMMddHHmmss)} is `20160919180226` so For **USER-2** it shouldn't be same value instead something like this `20160919180347` (a newer value of time function)

Comment: If multiple users run on parallel, same date will happen. So what do you expect if 2 users encounter the same date?

Comment: @KirilS. exactly you got my point. Users are running in parallel and same date is happen for all of them. I just want different date for each of them. Thanks

Comment: But is your goal to generate a valid (but unique) date-time stamp, or any unique entity, which does not have to be datetime, although has to be built on it?

Comment: @KirilS. thanks for your reply again. Yes my goal is to generate a valid (but unique) date-time stamp :)

Answer (score 0):

[__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function returns current timestamp either in milliseconds since [Unix epoch start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or according to pattern you specify. The function respects [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.

The weak point of your approach is that when it comes to high loads you can have more than one user calling this function at the same second you will get identical timestamps so I would suggest one of the following approaches:

1. Increase precision of your __time() function to milliseconds level like:

   ```
   ${__time(yyyyMMddHHmmss---SSS)}
   ```

   [image: time milliseconds]
2. Concatenate [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function with __time() function so each timestamp is followed by current virtual user number like:

   [image: Time + threadnum]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on enhancing your JMeter tests with Functions.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, appreciated your effort. I have tried above mentioned approaches but doesn't work at all. still the getting the same time for all users

Comment: You nailed it, I'm a liar and images are shopped